# IsNullOrEmpty Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a null value in my database which gives me an error if I try perform any mathematical operations on it.  I tried putting this in my controller action:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g) Then
            item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g = 0
End If
```

This my model for the field:

```
Public Property Fiber_TD_g() As Nullable(Of Double)
```

However, it says "Nullable object must have a value." on the `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g) Then` line.  How can I check if the "string" (it's a double, not a string) is empty and default it to zero, properly?

**Edit:**

I tried a suggestion below, and I no longer get an error in my controller, but instead in my View.  It says, "Nullable object must have a value." on the line `FiberTotal += item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g` in my view.

```
Dim food = db.Tbl_Food_Logs.Where(Function(x) x.FLog_Employee_ID = empId And x.FLog_Created_Date >= date2 And x.FLog_Created_Date < tomorrow)

For Each item In food

    If IsDBNull(item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g) Then
        item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g = 0
    End If

Next
Return View(food)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As its name implies, `String.IsNullOrEmpty` is a *string* operation. It won't work if you pass a `double`. Instead check to see if it `Is Nothing`:

```
If item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g Is Nothing Then
            item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g = 0
End If
```

This operation is common enough that VB has a shortcut, called the *null coalescing operator* (2-argument `If`):

```
item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g = If(item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g, 0)
```

When `If` has two arguments, it returns the first argument if it's not null and the second if it is.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was my answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the additional "null coalescing operator."  This is a common operation for me, too, so it's good to see this.

Answer (score 2):

```
If IsNull(item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g) Then
        item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g = 0
End If
```

or

```
If Trim(item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g) Then
        item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g = 0
End If
```

Comment: "try this...may work.."? You don't seem too sure of yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of string IsNullOrEmpty as checking for an uninitialiaed string variable, not as a check for an object being null. I think you want something like this, for maximum security.

```
 If Not item Is Nothing Then
        If Not item.TBL_food Is Nothing Then
            If Not item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g Is Nothing Then
                'do something
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This is the same answer as Gabes (I can't see who said it first).  It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change model part to:

```
public double? Fiber_TD_g { get; set; }
```

and then

```
item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g = item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g.HasValue ? item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g.Value : 0;
```

Comment: The poster is writing VB; I don't see C# as being very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check for:

```
If item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g.Equals(Nothing) Then
   item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g = 0
End If
```

Comment: How can `Fiber_TD_g` ever hold the value of `DbNull`?

Answer (score 0):

```
item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_g = item.Tbl_Food.Fiber_TD_GetValueOrDefault()
```